Magical red sphere, in a Smallville TV show
Does anyone remember a scene from the Smallville TV show, where Lionel Luthor is lying on a bed in a room and the camera takes into his eye and shows some magical red spinning sphere?
Does this sound familiar to anyone?
Does anyone know from which episode is that?

Makes me think a bit of the Orb, but it's more bluish.

"magical red spinning sphere" immediately makes me think of Alias.
